# Can I make an html page somewhere on online server that uses HTTPS free

Tags: android, html, https, webview, server

I need an HTML page that uses HTTPS. That page basically uses a javascript library. And I will call that page from my android application in web View to test the functionality of the library if it is working or not.

Basically HTTPS is a must to use that library in the HTML page. 
Is there any service that provides a free trial for such a development process?? 
Or any other way??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Visual Studio code's Go live plugin. 
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer .
This uses live server and places our HTML inside that.

Comment: Does it makes it SSL (HTTPS) ?? Not HTTPS??

Comment: Thanks to @Hardi By default VS code runs the html file on http protocol on online server but one can integrate it with ssl to run https for more information watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v4jgr0ppw8Q) video